# Why are functions not considered as named type?

Tags: swift, types, named

This is directly from Swift Developer Guide.

> In Swift, there are two kinds of types: named types and compound types. A named type is a type that can be given a particular name when it is defined. Named types include classes, structures, enumerations, and protocols. For example, instances of a user-defined class named MyClass have the type MyClass. In addition to user-defined named types, the Swift standard library defines many commonly used named types, including those that represent arrays, dictionaries, and optional values.
>   ....
>   A compound type is a type without a name, defined in the Swift language itself. There are two compound types: function types and tuple types.

Functions also have names, why are functions considered compound type instead of named type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions have both a name and a type. Functions's name denotes the *name* of that function alone; it does not denote the *type* of that function.

In fact, names and types of functions are independent of each other:

- Multiple functions with the same name are allowed to have different type, and
- Multiple functions with the same types are allowed to have different names.

Here is an example of two functions with the same name and different types:

```
func one(x: Double, y: Double) -> Bool {
    return true
}
func one(x: Double) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

The compound type of the first function `one` is "a function taking a `Double` and a `Double`, and returning a `Bool`", while the type of the second function `one` is "a function taking a `Double` and returning a `Bool`".

Here is an example of two functions of the same type, but with different names:

```
func one(x: Double) -> Bool {
    return true
}
func two(x: Double) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

The compound type of both functions is "a function taking a `Double` and returning a `Bool`". Both functions `one` and `two` are *instances* of that compound type.

Answer (score -1):

Functions aren't a type, that is why functions are not considered compound type. It's also the reason why functions aren't on that list.

Types are classes, enumerations and such. Functions are close to the language, while classes and such are object-oriented ways of working.

Comment: Function types are considered compound type according to the developer guide.

Comment: Functions are not a type (like variables aren't), but they _have_ a type. And _function types_ are considered to be _compound types_ and OP wants to know why.

Comment: But that doesn't mean a function is a type, the return type can be compound types, right?